# Run timer in app and when app is in background

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I need to run a timer when the user is in app and also when the app is in background.

The context is: if he is on a specific view controller, after 5 min will be redirected to main view controller. The timer should redirect him if the app stays in background and enters the app. Any idea how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with a normal `NSTimer` as there is no support for backgrounding. It is however achievable very easily using another method.

In your AppDelegate you have two methods. `applicationWillResignActive` and `applicationDidBecomeActive`. In the resign method you simply need to persist the current `NSDate` into the `NSUserDefaults` and in the active method, retrieve it and compare it against the current `NSDate` to get the amount of time the app was inactive for.

Code examples:

```
func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    let date = NSDate()
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(date, forKey: "DateTimer")
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    if let persistedDate = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("DateTimer") as? NSDate {
        let difference = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([.Second], fromDate: persistedDate, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])
        let differenceSeconds = difference.second
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way for doing this in Swift 3:

1. First take current time in seconds and save it into user defaults

   ```
   func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
       let date = NSDate()
       let resignTime = Int64(date.timeIntervalSince1970)
       UserDefaults.standard.set(resignTime, forKey: "logOutTime")
   }
   ```
2. When an app become active you may compare last active time(which is saved into user defaults) with the current time. (Note: both of elements have to be in one format)

   ```
   func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
       if let resignTime = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "logOutTime") as? Int64 {
           let date = NSDate()
           let currentTime = Int64(date.timeIntervalSince1970)
           debugPrint("diff: ", currentTime-resignTime)
           let diff = currentTime-resignTime
           if diff >= 300{ //checking difference of time which you expect
           }
       }
   }
   ```

And that's all. You can do whatever you want if condition is true.