# How to keep timer in running state within the app itself?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I have a scenario that I have to fire a timer in home screen.When user goes to another screen or user roaming within the app this time the timer which was fired in home screen should be running and timer label must update.Finally when user comes back to home screen timer and timer label should be updating according to timer value.How to achieve this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use singleton class and use timer from there

Comment: you can do this in background thread `dispatch_async()`

Comment: I am storing timer value in singleton class.Value updating in singleton class but label not updating when come back to home screen.

Answer (score 0):

**u can run in  dispatch_queue_t queue:**

```
  dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // perform on main
           //your method for running timer:
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.Its working but when - (void)viewDidLoad method calls its not working.But timer fire method executing.

Comment: I did't get it ... can u elaborate ur issue .. if the code working please accept it as a answer @UdayEega

Comment: If we go to another(from home) VC and come back to the same(Home) VC its working.But In my case Im calling Home VC from side menu so that - (void)viewDidLoad of Home VC is calling.In this case label not updating.But timer running.

Comment: u need to update ur label text in view -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{ };  because ur VC already loaded .

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is put your timer in AppDelegate and create a method in AppDelegate to start/stop the Timer.create protocol in AppDelegate and call that delegate method while timer selector is called.implement that protocol in HomeVC

```
 var Timer = NSTimer()
 var workTime = 0
 func startTimer()
 {
    self.Timer =  NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.countDownValue(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

 }
 func countDownValue(dt: NSTimer)
 {
        self.workTime += 1
        delegate?.updateValueofLabel(self.workTime)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with a normal NSTimer as there is no support for backgrounding. It is however achievable very easily using another method.
In your AppDelegate you have two methods. applicationWillResignActive and applicationDidBecomeActive. In the resign method you simply need to persist the current NSDate into the NSUserDefaults and in the active method, retrieve it and compare it against the current NSDate to get the amount of time the app was inactive for.

**Code examples:**

```
func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    let date = NSDate()
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(date, forKey: "DateTimer")
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    if let persistedDate = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("DateTimer") as? NSDate {
        let difference = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([.Second], fromDate: persistedDate, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])
        let differenceSeconds = difference.second
    }
}
```

The code take it from here:[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39873470/run-timer-in-app-and-when-app-is-in-background)